# How to implement listen function in react-router-dom v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm updating a react project's packages, implemented with `react-router-dom v5`. I've updated `react-router-dom` to `v6`. I've used `this.props.history` in a lot of `components`, and because of that, I don't need to change its structure, so I decided to create a wrapper that has that functionality and pass the components to it as a prop to don't change a lot of code. Here's the wrapper:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useLocation, useNavigate, useNavigationType, useParams } from "react-router";

export function withRouter(Child) {
  return (props) => {
    const [callBack,setCallBack] = React.useState();
    const location = useLocation();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const action = useNavigationType();
    const params = useParams();
    const match = {
      params: params
    }
    const history = {
      push: (url, onMount) => {
        if (onMount)
          setTimeout(() => navigate(url), 100)
        else
          navigate(url);

      },
      listen: (callback) => {
        setCallBack(callback);
      }
    }
    React.useEffect(() => {
      if (callBack) {
        callBack(location,action)
      }
    }, [location])

    return <Child {...props} history={history} location={location} match={match} />;
  }
}
```

I've used my wrapper in a component like this:

```
function action(params) {
    return (
        <Layout {...params}>
            <PageInfo title={Utils.i18n('notificationList', true)} icon="ti-bell"/>
            <NotificationList {...params}/>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export default withRouter(action);
```

And Here's the `listen` function on `componentDidMount` of the wrapped component:

```
componentDidMount(): void {
        this.props.history.listen((location, action) => {
            const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());
            if (params.id) {
                this.setState({id:params.id})
            }
        });
        this.getNotification();
        Utils.scrollToTop();
 }
```

My problem in this update is the `listen` functionality, which existed in `react-router-dom v5`. Because after any state change in the `Child` prop, all states cleared, so `callBack` is always undefined, and I couldn't implement `listen` functionality in my `wrapper`. In this part of the code, the callback is always undefined:

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
      if (callBack) {
        callBack(location,action)
      }
    }, [location])
```

Does anyone know how to implement my wrapper's `listen` functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only overt issue I see here are missing `useEffect` dependencies. `callback` and `action` are both missing.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (callback) {
    callback(location, action);
  }
}, [action, callback, location]);
```

A much more covert issue is saving a function into React state via the setState updater function. The setState function accepts a value to update the state ***or*** a callback function that is passed the previous state value and is expected to return the next state value. If you want to save a callback function into state you'll need to use the callback function syntax and return the callback function you want to save into state.

```
listen: (callback) => {
  setCallback(() => callback); // not setCallback(callback)
}
```

Full code:

```
export const withRouter = Component => props => {
  const [callback, setCallback] = React.useState();
  const location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const action = useNavigationType();
  const params = useParams();

  const match = { params };

  const history = {
    push: (url, onMount) => {
      if (onMount) {
        setTimeout(() => navigate(url), 100);
      } else {
        navigate(url);
      }
    },
    listen: (callback) => {
      setCallback(() => callback);
    }
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (callback) {
      callback(location, action);
    }
  }, [action, callback, location]);

  return <Component {...props} {...{ history, location, match }} />;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and answering my question. But, unfortunately after initializing `callback` on listen, in `useEffect` it will be always undefined. I've updated my answer for more description. Could you please read it again?

Comment: @MajidM. I had to copy your code into a sandbox to debug and find any other issue. There was an issue with how you were trying to save the `callback` into state. I've updated my answer.